# VSCode Python Intellisense: Doesn't show methods of a imported python class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Why VSCode Intellisense dont show methods of imported class?

```
from tinydb import TinyDB
db = TinyDB('db.json')
db. # Here I dont have any methods of TinyDB object in suggestions list
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to fix this problem. 
Even though there is a correct path to git in my PATH, VSCode needs value "git.path" in settings.json. Don't foreget """ if your path contains spaces.

This string in settings.json helps me: "git.path": """c:\Program Files\Git\cmd"""